# Flash website display blank page on server

Tags: html, flash, web

I have a website made in flash uploaded on a server. It was working fine tomorrow and today it shows blank page, why so ?? 
this is the link "[http://www.sudhanshushandilya.com"](http://sudhanshushandilya.com) . There's an index.html page and main.swf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you navigate to the SWF directly, it works, which tells me that the problem is how you're embedding it. Have you updated your flash player in the mean time? 10.2 was released recently (If you're on Chrome, this will probably happen automatically)

I took a quick look at your JavaScript embed code, and that's a lot of code :D

Can you try SWFObject and tell me if it works: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: nothing is happening.....when i tried using swfobject, it says u dont have permission to use on this servcer and  a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request......

Comment: you don't have permission to use swfobject on the server? that's weird, since js is executed on the client, so it shouldn't be a problem. perhaps this is where your error is coming from - it's more a server problem than a flash/js problem. can you get in touch with your server admins?

Comment: I uploaded the swfobject itself. That is also not working. Please check the below links : 

www.sudhanshushandilya.com/swfobject
www.sudhanshushandilya.com/swfobject/index-dynamic.html

Comment: Both of those URLs return 404, did you remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not the problem but you have an error in this file  "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://sudhanshushandilya.com/music/track.mp3"